# PHP even numbers generating

Tags: php

I'm somewhat new to PHP, been reading a few books and I've never seen a loop where it gets you all the even numbers(for example from 1 to 10), so I decided to try it myself:

```
for($i=0;$i<10 && $i % 2===0;$i++)
echo $i;
```

Tried with only double == as well.

And this,

```
    $i=0;
do echo $i; while($i++<10 && $i % 2 ==0);
```

Can't seem to figure out how to use 2 conditions in the same statement.

Would appreciate the help!

Thanks.

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i+2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use this code

```
for( $i=0; $i<=10; $i++ )
{ 
    if( $i%2 == 0 ){
        echo $i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop is breaking entirely when the second condition fails the first time. On the first iteration: 0 is less than 10, and it is even, so the loop iterates. On the second iteration: 1 is less than 10, but is odd, so the loop **breaks**.

Your code is the equivalent of this:

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
    if ($i % 2 !==0 ) {
        break;
    }

    echo $i;
}
```

> 0

You can eliminate the second condition of your `for` loop to prevent the breakage and rely exclusive on a third expression to increment $i by two each iteration.

```
for($i=0; $i<10; $i = $i + 2) {
    echo $i;
}
```

> 02468

Answer (score 1):

The second statement in a for-loop is/are the condition(s) which gets checked every loop. so if it fails your loop stops. what you need will look somewhat like this:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    if ($i % 2 == 0)
        echo $i;
```

So the loop will run over every number but only print out the even ones.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop.
Range can create a range with third parameter step 2.

```
$arr = range(0,20,2);
Echo implode(" ", $arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/S3JWV

Comment: you are printing  the array but he want to display by using echo

Comment: @Akshay fair enough. But still no need for a loop.

Comment: but we want to display the number as it is related to pattern .why not loop?

Comment: @Akshay generally looping should be avoided if you can. Especially if it's only simple tasks you loop. In this case if it's not a xy problem, you don't need to loop as I demonstrated. Even if it is a xy problem and OP needs the even integer to something else it's far better to create the array with the numbers you need and then foreach the array and use the values. Looping each value and skipping every other is inefficient, clumsy and there is a risk you make a mistake and remove the if() or code outside it. But this is my opinion, you and others may have a different opinion.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also regular loop and get the evens by formula:

```
for($i=0; $i<10 ;$i++) {
    $j = $i * 2;
    // do somthing with $j witch loop over 10 first evens...
}
```